# How to install Jekyll on Debian

Tags: ruby, rubygems, jekyll

I'm following the "[Jekyll on Debian](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/installation/other-linux/)" directions step-by-step for installing Jekyll on my Debian 10.1:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby-full build-essential zlib1g-dev
echo '# Install Ruby Gems to ~/gems' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export GEM_HOME="$HOME/gems"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/gems/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
gem install jekyll bundler
```

but it doesn't work. Here is the output:

```
$ gem install jekyll bundler
Building native extensions. This could take a while...
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:76: warning: Insecure world writable dir /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/home/mark/gems/bin in PATH, mode 040777
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/home/mark/gems/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7/ext
/usr/bin/ruby2.5 -r ./siteconf20200102-7165-18dxplz.rb extconf.rb
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/usr/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)2.5
    --with-ssl-dir
    --without-ssl-dir
    --with-ssl-include
    --without-ssl-include=${ssl-dir}/include
    --with-ssl-lib
    --without-ssl-lib=${ssl-dir}/lib
    --with-openssl-config
    --without-openssl-config
    --with-pkg-config
    --without-pkg-config
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:541:in `try_link0'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:559:in `try_link'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:661:in `try_ldflags'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:1821:in `pkg_config'
    from extconf.rb:65:in `pkg_config_wrapper'
    from extconf.rb:92:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/home/mark/gems/extensions/x86-linux/2.5.0/eventmachine-1.2.7/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/home/mark/gems/gems/eventmachine-1.2.7 for inspection.
Results logged to /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/home/mark/gems/extensions/x86-linux/2.5.0/eventmachine-1.2.7/gem_make.out
Successfully installed bundler-2.1.3
Parsing documentation for bundler-2.1.3
Done installing documentation for bundler after 19 seconds
1 gem installed
```

and here is the log file:

```
"gcc -o conftest -I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/ruby-2.5.0 -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0/ruby/backward -I/usr/include/ruby-2.5.0 -I. -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/ruby2.5-qqUyFd/ruby2.5-2.5.5=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC conftest.c  -L. -L/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu -L. -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic     -lruby-2.5  -lpthread -lgmp -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc"
/usr/lib/ruby/2.5.0/mkmf.rb:395: warning: Insecure world writable dir /srv/dev-disk-by-label-data/home/marcotrapanese/gems/bin in PATH, mode 040777
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: int main(int argc, char **argv)
4: {
5:   return 0;
6: }
/* end */

"pkg-config --exists openssl"
| pkg-config --libs openssl
=> "-lssl -lcrypto\n"
```

The warning about the permissions on the `gems/bin` folder is weird, because it was created by the installer, not by me.

It says "You have to install development tools first", but I've already installed them. Furthermore the error message doesn't tell what it thinks is missing.

Why does following such a simple procedure fail?

Comment: Back when I lived on Mint and Ubuntu I found I needed to update my configuration to the latest before beginning an install: `sudo apt-get update` will do that.

Comment: @theTinMan I always do that before doing anything. I didn't upgrade already installed packages, though.

Comment: Done. Nothing has changed.

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.6.0`. [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/).

Comment: @theTinMan, I don't agree with your edits. I was trying to install `Jekyll` on `Debian` following the instruction for `Debian`.

Comment: @Casper, the content of the log file is already there :-)

Comment: @anothermh, it works. Yours should be an answer, rather a comment. I'm astonished: I RTFM and it was not enough. And their instructions are *wrong*.